# Why does std::chrono::time_point not behave as expected?

Tags: c++, c++11, time, semantics, std

```
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
    using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<clock>;

    auto tp_now = clock::now();
    auto tp_min = time_point::min();

    bool b1 = tp_now > tp_min;
    bool b2 = (tp_now - tp_min) > std::chrono::seconds{ 0 };
    cout << boolalpha << b1 << endl << b2 << endl;
}
```

The expected output is:

> true
>
> true

But the actual output is:

> true
>
> false

Why does `std::chrono::time_point` not behave as expected?

Comment: Coliru: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4ee25ea413140aa8 Anyway, Wandbox printed true false

Comment: I think it's integer overflow

Comment: `tp_now - tp_min` is negative on Wandbox. I think Danh is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With:

```
using clock = std::chrono::system_clock;
using time_point = std::chrono::time_point<clock>;
```

`time_point` is implemented as if it stores a value of type Duration indicating the time interval from the start of the Clock's epoch. (See [`std::chrono::time_point`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point))

The `duration` member type of `clock` (and of `time_point`) is capable of representing negative durations.

Thus `duration` in your implementation may be implemented with a back-end signed integer, (it can be implemented with unsigned integer but with a complicated comparison).

In that particular implementation,

```
time_point::min();
time_point t(clock::duration::min());
time_point t(clock::duration(std::numeric_limits<Rep>::lowest()));
```

and `tp_now` is greater than `zero`, thus when you subtract them, you get an integer overflow because the result is larger than `std::numeric_limits<Rep>::max()`. In implementation with signed back-end, it's undefined behavior, in implementation with unsigned back-end, I don't know about it, but I guess its special comparison will make its `false`.

In [this example](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/1cv5LtsKAX7GjbU2), `tp_min` is `-9223372036854775808` ticks from its epoch, that number is the same with `std::numeric_limits<duration::rep>::lowest()`

---

TL;DR; It's integer overflow. Don't use

```
(tp1 - tp2) > std::chrono::duration<whatever_rep>::zero
```

Instead, use

```
tp1 > tp2
```